# Angular: data is not showing up in UI

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to access values in a list object, but data not showing up in UI, not sure why?
i can see the data in the console log. Below are the angular model interface i am using and
angular class,HTML code and Mock data, what am i doing wrong ?

**Interfaces**

```
export interface MycodeType {
    SpecialCode?: Mycodes[];
}

export interface Mycodes {
    SpeicalCode: number;
    SpecialCodeDescription: string;
    SpecialProvidedStatus: string;
}
```

**My  Angular Component file:**

```
            export class SpecialCodesComponent implements OnInit {
            
              @Input('sFC') specialFeatureCodes: MycodeType;
            
              constructor() {}
              specialCodesColumns: any[];
              ngOnInit(): void {
                
                this.specialFeatureCodesColumns = [
                  { field: 'specialCode', header: 'Special Code', width:'125%' },
                  { field: 'specialDescription', header: 'Special Code Description', width:'75%' },
                  { field: 'providedDerived', header: 'Provided/Derived', width:'125%' },
                ];
             }
            
            }
```

**HTML:**

```
            <div *ngIf="specialCodes?.SpecialCode.length>0" class="row"
                style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 25px; text-align:center">
                <fm-table [columns]="specialCodesColumns" [value]="specialCodes.SpecialCode">
                    <ng-template fmTemplate="header" let-columns>
                        <tr>
                            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">{{col.header}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template fmTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
```

In the console log i see the data
SpecialCode: Array [ {…}, {…} ]

*But data is not showing up in UI

*Mock data is that i am using to populate on UI screen:*

```
                "SpecialCodes":{ 
                           "SpecialCode":[
                           {
                              "SpecialCode": "118",
                              "SpecialCodeDescription": "some Second data",
                              "SpecialCodeProvidedStatus": "Provided"
                           },
                           {
                              "SpecialCode": "127",
                              "SpecialCodeDescription": "some data test",
                              "SpecialCodeProvidedStatus": "Derived"
                           }
```

Comment: What is `fm-table` component? It might be the issue of that component.

Comment: that is our custom table component, it is actually table